# Reading actionscript3 compressed json in python

Tags: python, actionscript-3, python-3.x

I have a file created with AS3 using code similar to this:

```
var jsonString : String;
var jo : Object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var data : ByteArray = new ByteArray;
data.writeObject(jo);
data.compress();
```

I can't change this code, I know the program use something like this to save JSON files on disk in a compressed and serialized binary format.

How can I read it in Python to create a plain text file with the inner json as plain text?

I can decompress with this code:

```
outPutFile = open(filenameOutput, "wb")
data = zlib.decompress(open(filename, "rb").read())
outPutFile.write(data)
```

but I don't know how to deserialize it. I read something about AMF but I really noob with this stuff.

Comment: No way I try using PyPI without sucess. I will make a AS3 program to transform the JSON to plain text and store it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "actionscript3 compressed JSON".

The fact that the data came from JSON originally is irrelevant; it's stored in [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format), which is what matters. And AMF isn't compressed JSON. It doesn't even handle the same data types as JSON (although it almost includes all of JSON's data types as a subset).

Adobe published a spec for AMF (or at least for [AMF3](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf), the version that you've got), so you can read the spec and write your own AMF deserializer.

But you don't have to; there are already parsers for AMF on PyPI and elsewhere. I don't know which one is best for your use, and StackOverflow isn't a good place to find recommendations for particular libraries anyway, but you can just search [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=AMF&submit=search) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+amf).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using AMF anywhere in that code + AMF would be pretty useless in that case since it's mostly useful for http communication.

Json is an universal format and AS3 does create just that. There is nothing special going on about reading Json made with AS3.

This being said the code you show does not save Json formatted data but its AS3 parsed value (json converted to AS3 Object/Array). What the code should save is a txt file with the content of the variable "jsonString". Instead your code use that string to create AS3 parsed objects and then save those as binary in file. That's the total opposite of what you want. If as you said you cannot change the code then Python will never be able to read and parse a binary file filled with AS3 objects.

The only solution seems to be loading those files into an AS3 app then convert those objects back to simple json string and save as txt file. Then python would be able to read it.

Comment: I beg to differ. [The documentation of writeObject() has one sentence and that is:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject%28%29) "_Writes an object into the byte array in **AMF** serialized format._"